# What is the expected behaviour of @PostConstruct in @Configuration classes?

Tags: java, spring

We are reusing a project that defines its beans with spring java-config (using @Configuration), and in one such class it has a `@PostConstruct` init method.

What is the expected behaviour here - when is this method invoked? In regard to beans, that is. I.e. does this method behave exactly as if the configuration class is a bean (and is it actually one?)

What we observe is that, depending on the operating system, it can be invoked before the beans that are `@Autowired` into the configuration class are initialized, and thus it ends up working with incomplete dependencies.

Comment: After the constructor, and after the Autowiring of dependencies has been completed.

Comment: You noticed differences dependending on the operating system? That is pretty odd! I haven't encountered any such problems when I have `@PostContstruct` inside `@Configuration`. Whenever I used it was called after autowiring has been performed

Comment: yes - sometimes it is invoked before the dependent beans are initialized, sometimes after.

Comment: @Zhuinden I meant in regard to other beans (I updated the question)

Comment: +1 I don't have any ideas (since I have never encountered the problem and thus cannot reproduce it), but the issue is very interesting!

Comment: indeed. I've never had this issue with regular beans, but it's the first time I use java-config, and I don't know of Configuration classes are treated as beans or not.

Comment: One idea would be to debug and see when the relevant post processors are called (probably `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Even for `@Configuration`, `@PostConstruct` behaves as expected - it gets invoked after the dependencies of the class are injected. Although this is a bit confusing (together with the fact that `@Configuration` classes are beans), it is correct.

The problem at hand was a hidden circular dependency introduced with the help of spring-security-oauth - it's a convoluted set of configurations that is beyond the scope of this discussion.

So, `@PostConstruct` can be invoked if the dependent beans are not fully initialized only in case of circular dependencies. If dependencies are supplied via setter or field injection the circular dependency is not reported, and instead incomplete beans are used.

Also something to note here is that it seems the circular dependency handling depends on the OS (which means some JVM or JRE differences).