# Spring dependency @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Say I have this dependency in a Spring `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
public SomeClass someClass(SomeClass1 someClass1, SomeClass2 someClass2, ...) {
  return new SomeClass(someClass1, someClass2, ...);
}
```

Say I want do do something in `@PostConstruct` that includes `someClass` dependency:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  someClass.doSomething();
}
```

This cannot be injected:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(SomeClass someClass) {
  someClass.doSomething();
}
```

causes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Lifecycle method annotation requires a no-arg method: ...
```

This cannot be autowired in the same config like this:

```
@Autowire
private SomeClass someClass;

@Bean
public SomeClass someClass(SomeClass1 someClass1, SomeClass2 someClass2, ...) {
  return new SomeClass(someClass1, someClass2, ...);
}
```

as that leads to:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'globalBus': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

A config can be split (so `@Bean` goes to the other config) and `@Import`-ed by this one and it works OK. Probably other solutoins exist - e.g. creating a separate initialization bean or so.

Is there a way to do this within one `@Configuration`?

**Edit**

As requested by @SotiriosDelimanolis, a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for the exception when using `@Autowired`:

```
public class ConfigPostConstructDependenciesPrb {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
      ctx.getBean(Service.class);
      ctx.close();
   }

   public static class Service {
      private final Dependency dependency;

      public Service(Dependency dependency) {
         this.dependency = dependency;
      }

      public void work() {
         System.out.println(dependency.getNum());
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append("Service [dependency=");
         sb.append(dependency);
         sb.append("]");
         return sb.toString();
      }
   }

   public static class Dependency {
      private final int num;

      public Dependency(int num) {
         this.num = num;
      }

      public int getNum() {
         return this.num;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append("SomeClass1 [num=");
         sb.append(num);
         sb.append("]");
         return sb.toString();
      }
   }

   @Configuration
   public static class BaseConfig {
      @Autowired
      private Service service;

      @Bean
      public Dependency dependency() {
         return new Dependency(42);
      }

      @Bean
      public Service service(Dependency dependency) {
         return new Service(dependency);
      }

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
         service.work();
      }
   }

   @Configuration
   @Import(BaseConfig.class)
   public static class Config {
      @Autowired
      private Service service;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Why cant/dont you `Inject` it?

Comment: Is `SomeClass` an inner class?

Comment: @PostConstruct is for your beans, not your configuration classes.  As user489041 said, you should just inject it into your bean, if that's where its being used.

Comment: Do you **have to** do the `@PostConstruct` in the `@Configuration` class? What kind of setup method is this?

Comment: Also, depending on what the rest of your config looks like, your `@Autowired` solution should work. Since it doesn't, you have other things interfering. Please clarify.

Comment: user489041 - Isn't Autowired == Inject? / Thunderforge - no / hyness - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548004 /  @SotiriosDelimanolis - yes, need to register listeners after all is wired. I'll try to post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: try using SpringBeanAutowiringSupport()

Answer (score 4):

(Tested in Spring 4.3.6)

Create a nested class inside your @Configuration and put there declarations of `@Autowired service` and `@PostConstruct init()`:

```
@Configuration
public static class BaseConfig {

    //...

    @Bean
    public Service service(Dependency dependency) {
        return new Service(dependency);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Setup {

        @Autowired
        private Service service;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            service.work();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is your full example updated accordingly.

Notice that you don't have to add explicit reference to `BaseConfig.Setup` (look at the `@Import` annotation before `Config` class - it only refers to `BaseConfig` itself).

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

public class ConfigPostConstructDependenciesPrb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        ctx.getBean(Service.class);
        ctx.close();
    }

    public static class Service {
        private final Dependency dependency;

        public Service(Dependency dependency) {
            this.dependency = dependency;
        }

        public void work() {
            System.out.println(dependency.getNum());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Service [dependency=");
            sb.append(dependency);
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public static class Dependency {
        private final int num;

        public Dependency(int num) {
            this.num = num;
        }

        public int getNum() {
            return this.num;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("SomeClass1 [num=");
            sb.append(num);
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class BaseConfig {
        @Bean
        public Dependency dependency() {
            return new Dependency(42);
        }

        @Bean
        public Service service(Dependency dependency) {
            return new Service(dependency);
        }

        @Configuration
        public static class Setup {
            @Autowired
            private Service service;

            @PostConstruct
            public void init() {
                service.work();
            }
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(BaseConfig.class)
    public static class Config {
        @Autowired
        private Service service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public class ConfigPostConstructDependenciesPrb  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BaseConfig.class);

            ctx.registerShutdownHook();
            ctx.getBean(Service.class);
            ctx.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Configuration
class BaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Bean
    public Dependency dependency() {
        return new Dependency(42);
    }

    @Bean
    public Service service(Dependency dependency) {
        return new Service(dependency);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.service.work();
    }
}

class Dependency {

    private int num;

    public Dependency() {

    }

    public Dependency(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return this.num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SomeClass1 [num=");
        sb.append(num);
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

class Service {

    private Dependency dependency;

    public Service() {

    }

    public Service(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void work() {
        System.out.println(dependency.getNum());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Service [dependency=");
        sb.append(dependency);
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the here difference compared to what I posted, removal of `Config` class? If so, that's not really solving anything.

Comment: Look at the modifiers, my classes are not static. I proved this example and it works.

Comment: Whether classes are static or not does not change anything (feel free to test yourself to confirm). You changed the code in a way that changes the initialization - you reduced the number of configs from 2 to 1 and eliminated import. Does it work if you import the configs as I did (i.e. `Config` imports `BaseConfig` and you initialize using `Config`)?

Comment: Show me what is the error when you test this code, because I tested my code before post and it works. May be you are having another fault.

Comment: I agree, it works, but it is not doing the same thing. You removed `Config` class and only use `BaseConfig`. If you try using multiple configurations (which I need), it breaks. See my previous comment for details.

Comment: The problem in your code is: The Spring Loader is trying to inject service when it is creating the bean (At the same time). To resolve that problem and create the service bean before the injection, You would interrupt the Spring life cycle and create the beans. Try implementing this interface "BeanFactoryPostProcessor" and register the beans in the method named "postProcessBeanFactory". It'll solve your problem.