# Spring configure the same bean at multiple @Configuration files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I faced situation when I need configure some beans at my core-module @Configuration file, and than finish configuration of core-module beans at top-level module @Configuration file. (*please see code below*)

***How to finish setup of core-module's SchedulerFactoryBean at facade's @Configuration file?***

*Core module scheduler configs:*

```
@Configuration
public class BaseSchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource,
                                                     JobFactory jobFactory,
                                                     @Qualifier("baseReusableJob") JobDetail baseReusableJob) {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobDetails(baseReusableJob);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

*Facade module scheduler configs:*

```
@Configuration
@Import(BaseSchedulerConfig.class)
public class FacadeSchedulerConfig {

    @Autowire
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

    // Question: which annotation use to inject module (facade) specific jobs into SchedulerFactoryBean
    public void lookup(@Qualifier("facadeSpecificJob") JobDetail facadeSpecificJob) {
        schedulerFactoryBean.setJobDetails(facadeSpecificJob);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations).

> The JSR-250 @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are generally considered best practice for receiving lifecycle callbacks in a modern Spring application.

Works with @Configuration as expected.

> [What is the expected behaviour of @PostConstruct in @Configuration classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548004/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-of-postconstruct-in-configuration-classes)